# Recursive compare - Hibernate Audit object + Javers

Tags: hibernate-envers, javers

I have following simple data model:

TestUser:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TEST_USER")
@Audited
public class TestUser implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
    @NotEmpty
    private String name;


    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "testUser", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    @OrderBy
    private Set<TestUserAddress> addresses = new HashSet<TestUserAddress>();

    // ...
}
```

TestUserAddress:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TEST_USER_ADDRESS")
@Audited
public class TestUserAddress implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2071806522133475539L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
    @NotEmpty
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "CITY", nullable = false)
    @NotEmpty
    private String city;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "TEST_USER_ID")
    @JsonBackReference
    private TestUser testUser;

    // ...
}
```

I have performed one operation to update TestUserAddress object - for example I changed TestUserAddress name:

```
    [TestUser]:
    - id = 1
    - name = "testName"
    - [TestUserAddress]:
        - name = "testAddressName" ===> changed to "testAddressName2"
        - city = "testAddressCity"
```

I developed some code to compare TestUser objects, like below:

```
// testUserId - ID of the object that I would like to compare
// startRevision/endRevision - revisions to compare - stored in Hibernate Envers audit tables

AuditReader testUserReader = AuditReaderFactory.get(em);

TestUser testUserStart = testUserReader.find(TestUser.class, testUserId, startRevision.intValue());

TestUser testUserEnd = testUserReader.find(TestUser.class, testUserId, endRevision.intValue());

Javers javers = JaversBuilder.javers().build();
Diff diff = javers.compare(testUserStart, testUserEnd);
```

but above code is not showing me change done for TestUserAddress.
If I run below code:

```
// testUserId - ID of the object that I would like to compare
// startRevision/endRevision - revisions to compare - stored in Hibernate Envers audit tables

AuditReader testUserReader = AuditReaderFactory.get(em);

TestUser testUserStart = testUserReader.find(TestUser.class, testUserId, startRevision.intValue());
Set<TestUserAddress> testUserAddressStart = testUserStart.getAddresses();

TestUser testUserEnd = testUserReader.find(TestUser.class, testUserId, endRevision.intValue());
Set<TestUserAddress> testUserAddressEnd = testUserEnd.getAddresses();

Javers javers = JaversBuilder.javers().build();
Diff diff = javers.compare(testUserStart, testUserEnd);
Diff diff2 = javers.compare(testUserAddressStart, testUserAddressEnd);
```

diff2 variable is showing me all changes done for TestUserAddress, however I would like to perform `compare` operation on root object to get the full lists done for object field and all child objects.

Do you know how can I do it?

I will appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: I tested your use case with Javers with the first example and I get a `Diff` that tells me the address has changed.  You need to illustrate how you're modifying the address.  Additionally, what version of Hibernate / Hibernate Envers are you using?

Comment: I am using Hibernate 5.1.0.Final + Javers 2.1.1. I noticed that when I use `@JsonManagedReference` property for `private Set<TestUserAddress> addresses = new HashSet<TestUserAddress>();` instead of `@JsonIgnore` then it' working for me. How to avoid this issue? I do not want to change annotation to `@JsonManagedReference`

Comment: That sounds like a Javers support question to me.  It certainly has no impact on the Hibernate Envers side.

Comment: @bontade could you simplify these snippets to show only your domain objects and javers code (without Hibernate)?